# Layout of fragment disintegrates when it dynamically replaces framelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an app with MainActivity that contains a FrameLayout which would be replaced by a fragment based on which item is clicked in the bottom layout. I have a fragment named "bookings" that must appear in the body area when "Bookings" option is clicked. The "bookings" fragment contains a spinner and a button that are placed at the center of screen inside of RelativeLayout. When the fragment's layout is placed directly inside of body of MainActivity, the spinner and button is centered, just the way I want it to be.

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottompanel"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- The FrameLayout goes here -->

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/city_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/center_space"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:dropDownVerticalOffset="20dp"
            android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
            android:popupBackground="#d5ddea"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        <Space
            android:id="@+id/center_space"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Done"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/center_space"
            android:onClick="doneButton" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:id="@+id/bottompanel">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Profile"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bookings_button"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_bookings"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bookings"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/games_button"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_tournaments"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Games"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But when I replace the FrameLayout with the fragment, the spinner disappears and the button moves at the top.

[image]

Code in activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottompanel"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_frame"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:id="@+id/bottompanel">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Profile"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bookings_button"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_bookings"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bookings"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/games_button"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_tournaments"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Games"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code in fragment_bookings.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/city_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/center_space"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:dropDownVerticalOffset="20dp"
    android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
    android:popupBackground="#d5ddea"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

<Space
    android:id="@+id/center_space"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Done"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/center_space"
    android:onClick="doneButton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code of onCreateView of bookings.java:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bookings, container, false);
    Spinner loc = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.city_spinner);
    String[] cities = new String[]{
            "Select a City",
            "ABC",
            "DEF",
            "GHI",
            "JKL",
            "MNO"
    };

    // Initializing an ArrayAdapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,cities
    );
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    loc.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
    loc.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id) {
            L1 = id;
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
    return v;

}
```

Code in MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.user.temporary;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        profile.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        bookings.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        games.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    private Activity myActivity;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.myActivity = this;
        LinearLayout profilebtn = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.profile_button);
        LinearLayout bookingsbtn = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.bookings_button);
        LinearLayout gamesbtn = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.games_button);
        profilebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                profile profileFragment = new profile();
                FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                trans.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, profileFragment);
                trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                trans.commit();
            }
        });
        bookingsbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bookings bookings_frame = new bookings();
                FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                trans.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, bookings_frame);
                trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                trans.commit();
            }
        });
        gamesbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                games games_frame = new games();
                FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                trans.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, games_frame);
                trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                trans.commit();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri){

    }

}
```

Comment: You've got the `<FrameLayout>`'s `layout_height` set to `wrap_content`. Change it to `match_parent`. Also, the `LinearLayout` wrapping it is currently useless. You can remove it, unless you're going to put something else in it.

Comment: yep, change <FrameLayout>'s layout_height to match_parent first. clean the build and run the simulator or program again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `height` of `FrameLayout` to `match_parent` from `wrap_content`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottompanel"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_frame"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But, didn't understand if the FrameLayout has been replaced by the fragment, and doesn't exist once the button is clicked, why does it's height propery matter anymore?

Comment: No, frame layout won't be replaced by Fragment. It holds your fragment like a container . Technically it's a parent layout for your fragment

Comment: Oh. I see. That was helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You have `match_parent` in the height for fragment layout. Try changing it to `wrap_content` and see if it works

Comment: No, still the same result.

Comment: The parent `LinearLayout` also seems to have `match_parent` for its height, try changing that

Comment: You probably meant changing the height of FrameLayout. But, thanks anyways. Happy coding.